# Flatten the CUBE

Tags: code-golf, string, geometry

Do you ever look at 3D shapes and think that we have 2 many dimensions. So let's make 3D into 1D! (See what I did there?)

## Task

Given a 2D representation of a cube (layout below), flatten it into a single string, based on pointers.

## The CUBE

This is the layout of the cube filled with no-ops (`,`) and pointers at the corners (`<>v^/`). The Navigation Pointer (NP) begins the program where shown.

```
         | NP begins here, moving right.
         V
         >,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,v
        ,                  ,,
       ,                  , ,
      ,                  ,  ,
     ,                  ,   ,
    ,                  ,    ,
   ,                  ,     ,
  ,                  ,      ,
 ,                  ,       ,
/,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,/        /
,                  ,       ,
,                  ,      ,
,                  ,     ,
,                  ,    ,
,                  ,   ,
,                  ,  ,
,                  , ,
,                  ,,
^,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,<
```

The NP continues moving right from the start until it meets a corner. Each corner has a default direction that, unless overridden at the corner by a pointer, will point the NP in a new direction. They are shown on the above diagram. The pointers in the program are `v^<>/` (the `/` points it either down or up, due to the layout there will never be any confusion between the two)

The NP stops moving when it reaches the `¶` symbol (Yes I know this is a multi-byte character, deal with it). Each character it goes over is added to the final output string except for the pointers, the no-op (`,`) and the `¶` symbol.

## Input

Input will be a multi-line string that matches the layout of the **CUBE** with the non-whitespace characters replaced with any character in the range `0x21` to `0x7E` and **at least** one instance of the EOF.

You may take input as:

- A multiline string
- A list of strings where each line is a new element in the list
- A 2D list of strings where each line is broken down into a list

## Output

The cube, flattened down into a single line string.

## Conditional Pointer

The NP has a boolean value that is used for something called a "conditional" pointer that begins at `true`.

The "conditional" pointer (`?`) is a pointer which will alternate the NP value between `true` and `false` every time it is used. Conditional pointers only take effects when used on the corners where 3 tracks (3-point corner) meet. If the value is `true` when the NP reaches the conditional pointer, the NP moves to the default direction in the CUBE image and, **after** being directed, the NP value is toggled. Therefore, if it is on `false`, the NP follows the non-default direction.

There will never be an instance where the NP goes towards a conditional and the default direction is the direction it just came from. Imagine that this is the left corner of the front face and the NP value is currently `true`:

```
      NP direction
      /
     ,
    ,
,,,?
   ,
   ,
```

This will never happen as the default direction will mirror it back to how it was.

If the conditional pointer is on an 3-point corner:

- It isn't added to the final string
- The NP value is toggled between `true` and `false` **after** the NP has been directed.
- If the NP value is `true`, the NP is redirected to the **default** direction. Otherwise, it is redirected to the **non-default** direction.

If it is on a track or a 2-point corner:

- It is added to the final string
- the value **is** toggled
- The IP **isn't** directed

## Something to watch out for

If a pointer is on a track and it **doesn't** point into spaces, the NP is directed into the new track, adds the next character to the final string and rotates the NP by 90 degrees to the right.

```
 abcd
   >e
  g f
 /
NP direction
```

would flatten to

```
(...) gef (...)
```

NOT

```
(...) g>def (...)
```

A `/` pointer doesn't redirect the NP in this instance as it may redirect into a space so

```
     f
     e
> ab/d
```

would become `ab/def`

## Rules

- The width, height and depth of the cube may change
- The height and depth of the cube will always be the same and will be half the width, so the width will always be even.
- The width will be between (inclusive) 6 and 60.
- There will always be an EOF (`¶`) that can be reached by the NP. E.g there will never be something like this in the cube: `<¶>` as the NP would never be able to reach the cube.
- As a space cannot be inserted into the cube's tracks, the final string shouldn't ever have a space in it.
- If a pointer is placed in one of the tracks (not on a corner) and it would direct the NP into spaces, the NP stays constant and the character is added to the final string.
- However, if the pointer keeps it on the track, the NP is directed and the pointer character isn't added
- As no-ops (`,`) aren't added to the final string, the final string shouldn't contain any `,` in it.
- You can assume that the input will be correct.
- This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code in *bytes* wins!

## Examples

```
Input
Output
-----
Input
Output

  abcdef
 ¶    ,g
q,,,,, h
p    ,i
onmlkj

abcdefghijklmnopq

-----

         >,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,v
        ¶                  ,,
       ,                  , ,
      ,                  ,  ,
     ,                  ,   ,
    ,                  ,    ,
   ,                  ,     ,
  ,                  ,      ,
 ,                  ,       ,
/,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,/        /
,                  ,       ,
,                  ,      ,
,                  ,     ,
,                  ,    ,
,                  ,   ,
,                  ,  ,
,                  , ,
,                  ,,
^,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,<

nothing

-----

                   Mr/~gm,Vc!r,0cbmPC@Zg9jb)7=m^ppwN*Nuk){r
                  c                                      ¶Z
                 J                                      ; #
                e                                      j  8
               ]                                      b   "
              #                                      `    4
             h                                      $     -
            p                                      n      2
           L                                      S       P
          B                                      ;        R
         @                                      J         D
        E                                      N          <
       O                                      \           p
      B                                      y            =
     |                                      9             ;
    T                                      x              [
   6                                      o               k
  !                                      L                =
 E                                      K                 ~
>mjmz6,?A*Q)^.a:IpGP"^bK}DSXL)2F!BV|"m6/                  T
a                                      A                 6
5                                      =                p
1                                      i               R
4                                      /              ?
-                                      Z             (
1                                      "            `
'                                      0           {
N                                      p          M
O                                      *         K
Z                                      J        $
"                                      (       d
4                                      +      o
f                                      U     g
i                                      v    b
U                                      ~   L
U                                      M  h
g                                      ^ D
2                                      (g
5]u*n<Ldn</9/XQyC444Va\m}W3Rf,rp"a@5cZB0

(Newlines added for readability)
Mr/~gmVc!r0cbmPC@Zg9jb)7=m^ppwN*Nuk){rZ#8"4-2PRD<p=;[k=~T
6pR?(`{MK$dogbLhDg0BZc5@a"prfR3W}m\aV444CyQX/9/ndLn*u]52g
UUif4"ZON'1-415amjmz6?A*Q)^.a:IpGP"^bK}DSXL)2F!BV|"m6KLox9
y\NJ;Sn$`bj;

-----

       NEWYORKCITYBABY!
      ¶              ,,
     ,              , ,
    ,              ,  ,
   ,              ,   ,
  ,              ,    ,
 ,              ,     ,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,      ,
,              ,     ,
,              ,    ,
,              ,   ,
,              ,  ,
,              , ,
,              ,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

NEWYORKCITYBABY!

-----

                          /{Y!_(=-)s<e!D^<+<+1o30d>QOx9kfu?3X2I:8],t>Ye~,Y9/6;u@
                         ]                                                    >Y
                        !                                                    1 )
                       c                                                    7  8
                      ^                                                    K   &
                     f                                                    K    9
                    M                                                    }     O
                   s                                                    _      ?
                  h                                                    N       e
                 ?                                                    u        ,
                g                                                    =         s
               >                                                    Q          M
              a                                                    0           9
             b                                                    c            (
            h                                                    {             c
           [                                                    m              *
          I                                                    R               %
         K                                                    E                >
        u                                                    5                 n
       W                                                    f                  ]
      }                                                    |                   y
     F                                                    E                    q
    )                                                    <                     ;
   X                                                    L                      S
  F                                                    M                       |
 u                                                    *                        Z
>XZpJ=L`+8ONRk?T7$qVr6-U^f14{>>ABEEP`Mjx&T[/&o*F=*qq{/                         e
¶                                                    <                        ^
+                                                    P                       C
.                                                    x                      m
;                                                    ^                     >
y                                                    4                    b
5                                                    v                   `
Q                                                    B                  c
2                                                    e                 r
a                                                    x                I
3                                                    1               Y
Q                                                    v              `
w                                                    ;             o
*                                                    S            h
E                                                    b           S
r                                                    6          P
M                                                    `         l
%                                                    M        A
-                                                    `       "
j                                                    \      s
}                                                    ~     J
$                                                    h    c
%                                                    p   O
I                                                    Z  Z
]                                                    N E
`                                                    3<
x^}}SI"-a3[%7U5EV}"UM?Aov|E_yjrMt<HAQ@}QAABO&y//R0$\2p

(Newlines added for readability)
]!c^fMsh?g>abh[IKuW}F)XFuXZpJ=L`+8ONRk?T7$qVr6-U^f14{ABEE
P`Mjx&T[/&o*F=*qq{*ML<E|f5ERm{c0Q=uN_}KK71Y)8&9O?esM9(c*%
>n]yq;S|Ze^Cm>b`crIY`ohSPlA"sJcOZE3NZph~\`M`6bS;;Sb6`M`\~
hpZN3p2\$0R//y&OBAAQ}@QAHtMrjy_E|voA?MU"}VE5U7%[3a-"IS}}^
x`]I%$}j-%MrE*wQ3a2Q5y;.+

-----

   %:biv+|?
  ¶      \+
 T      c ,
?{yX<//v  "
i      [ @
Q      Tj
U8sUNl.?

%:biv+|+"@jT[[T.lNUs8UQi{yXXy{T

-----

     FCf2hoYA)&*j
    F          ¶#
   3          p (
  &          ~  w
 ;          *   t
39Hq{F'MmmO/    9
5          \   D
-          |  }
8          c l
a          25
GKa"<0/7MG[?

FCf2hoYA)&*j#(wt9D}l5[GM7/0"aKGa8-53;&3FFCf2hoYA)&*j#(wt9D}l52c|\*~p

-----

           #S^[WNk3;9v;e2\h!@CI#Il?
          G                      g`
         $                      2 \
        V                      9  S
       m                      Y   b
      6                      )    *
     U                      '     V
    [                      g      V
   I                      8       X
  <                      T        U
 K                      ¶         C
?ozMt+xxxxutvQgkx&D9I/<v          '
w                      K         p
V                      y        h
(                      R       y
e                      P      i
]                      !     x
Z                      /    s
y                      w   '
#                      X  4
c                      ~ W
Z                      E,
~IdXPYS.Lc49lC~vjULUBv.?

(Newlines added for readability)    
#S^[WNk3;9v;e2\h!@CI#Il`\Sb*VVXUC'phyixs'4WE~Xw/!PRyKKyRP!/wX~E
.vBULUjv~Cl94cL.SYPXdI~Zc#yZ]e(VwozMt+xxxxutvQgkx&D9I//I9D&xkgQ
vtuxxxx+tMzoK<I[U6mV$G#S^[WNk3;9v;e2\h!@CI#Ilg29Y)'g8T
```

Comment: No problem :) Really nice challenge btw! :)

Comment: @HyperNeutrino I kinda feel guilty now that the bounty has started. This was a project that I was working on but gave up and decided to post. So I can just polish off my old solution and post it for the bounty! I'll only do that  if there are no answer by the end of the week, though

Comment: @RandomUser go ahead and post an answer now, people will be more inclined to answer when they have something to beat. And don't feed guilty, it's the equivalent of 5 answer upvotes.

Comment: @programmer5000 It's not finished and no where near golfed but I should get it done in a few days

Comment: @RandomUser derp

Answer (score 11):

## [Vim](https://www.vim.org), 971 bytes

```
Go<C-v><C-v><C-v>
elsei'<C-v><C-v><C-v><C-r>t'==<Esc>^"zC<C-v><C-v><C-v>
let@b=<Esc>^"fC<C-v><C-v><C-v>
let@O=<Esc>^"xC:if'<C-v><C-v><C-v><C-r>0'==' '<Esc>^"yC<C-v><C-v><C-v>
norm <Esc>^"wC<C-v><C-v><C-v>
let@m='<Esc>^"vC'<C-v><C-v><C-r>f0<C-v><C-v><C-v>
el<C-v><C-v><C-v>
if'<C-v><C-v><C-v><C-r>m'=='<Esc>^"aCyl:if'<C-v><C-v><C-v><C-r>0'!=' '<C-v><C-v><C-v>
let@T=<Esc>^"hC457||<C-v><C-v><C-v><C-r>t==147<C-v><C-r>vlk'<Esc>^"iC@n:if<C-v><C-v><C-v><C-r>t==<Esc>^"jC@nlylh<C-r>y<C-r>x'>'<C-r>w@m<C-r>z234568<C-r>wl<C-r>vj'<C-v>
el<C-r>wl<C-r>vl'<C-v>
en<C-v>
<Esc>^"rC@nhyll<C-r>y<C-r>x'<'<C-r>w@m<C-r>z1248<C-r>wh<C-r>vk'<C-v>
el<C-r>wh<C-r>vh'<C-v>
en<C-v>
<Esc>^"lC@nkylj<C-r>y<C-r>x'^'<C-r>w@m<C-r>z234568<C-r>wk<C-r>vl'<C-v>
el<C-r>wk<C-r>vk'<C-v>
en<C-v>
<Esc>^"uC@njylk<C-r>y<C-r>x'v'<C-r>w@m<C-v>
el<C-r>wj<C-r>vj'<C-v>
en<C-v>
<Esc>^"dC<C-r>j<C-r>i<C-r>z38<C-r>vhj'<C-v>
el<C-r>x'/'<C-v>
en<C-v>
<Esc>^"sC<C-r>j178<C-v>
if<C-v><C-r>b<C-r>vj<C-r>al'<C-r>vhj'<C-v>
el<C-r>vh'<C-v>
en<C-r>f1<C-v>
en<C-r>z147<C-v>
if<C-v><C-r>b<C-r>vlk<C-r>al'<C-r>vj'<C-v>
el<C-r>vh'<C-v>
en<C-r>f1<C-v>
en<C-r>z134<C-v>
if<C-v><C-r>b<C-r>vh<C-r>aj'<C-r>vlk'<C-v>
el<C-r>vk'<C-v>
en<C-r>f1<C-v>
en<C-r>z457<C-v>
if<C-v><C-r>b<C-r>vlk<C-r>ah'<C-r>vj'<C-v>
el<C-r>vl'<C-v>
en<C-r>f1<C-v>
en<C-v>
el<C-r>x'?'<C-r>f(<C-v><C-r>b+1)%2<C-v>
en<C-v>
<Esc>^"qC"tyl:if'<C-v><C-r>t'=='>'<C-r>w@r<C-r>z'<'<C-r>w@l<C-r>z'v'<C-r>w@d<C-r>z'^'<C-r>w@u<C-r>z'/'<C-r>w@s@e<C-r>z'?'<C-r>w@q@e<C-r>z'█'<C-r>wHdG"op<C-v>
k<C-r>z','<C-r>w@e<C-v>
el<C-r>w"Oyl@e<C-v>
en<C-v>
@c<Esc>^"cCma@myl<C-r>y<C-r>w`a@g<C-r>w@m<C-v>
en<C-v>
<Esc>^"eC<C-r>j58<C-r>vl'<C-r>z178<C-r>vj'<C-r>z38<C-r>vhj'<C-r>z134<C-r>vh'<C-r>z35<C-r>vk'<C-r>z<C-r>i<C-v>
en<C-v>
<Esc>^"gC:let@t=''<C-v>
h<C-r>h1<C-v>
en<C-v>
<C-v><Esc>k<C-r>h2<C-v>
en<C-v>
l<C-r>h3<C-v>
en<C-v>
l<C-r>h4<C-v>
en<C-v>
j<C-r>h5<C-v>
en<C-v>
j<C-r>h6<C-v>
en<C-v>
h<C-r>h7<C-v>
en<C-v>
h<C-r>h8<C-v>
en<C-v>
<C-v><Esc>kl<Esc>^"nC1l<Esc>"mx"bxgg
@c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZZLc9MwEIDvOeqQSy@pKeOmBPJyHi01cWugQJ@UUphCMzhPx5bTkLZJnD7O/AJ@IH@krGTFjh0zLINnYu@u99uVdmUpo4eHnYtkMplo08t2TwaJXMmqulSXpjoz0/aV1mBqx1cPmTrRN3od7p4Ddzklg83lLv2LoZMCbewDjsrejnRwJ52cl4zdRQCHBQAHQ3dpEHSZBZ1FOGEpTV0pVW5v@RBVNa9UkmREbUb2dK0PpHgDBgsM1KUmcclEfiGTseaQaaGolMpVMqZkZMlsDFykTOwnE0ANgTJdSjm1Kah8QQHGJCNbMCCaAUOBsV1qcaYeyWSL8JSLdkBdA2W51ObUiFOemyXG5rm1dGKRHpkWq5BTjHkiZwOHS3DIV6qslEnSAJYYVA58xUBJJ88fU1azmSsk575/ci0qvqtJDEvmtfZc7bArdCUU1ZyLSuddxfhrMumsgveTfPpxwZ/Kd126Ev3nK9Br25BMvU5QEHihWiDwOl@DkGXCpdYGscbE71z89fMHKG9aO9LFIJmwwZJhL9teiaVDl3IZ8mpNyNzUHUNzXNb28TdD64pueMNqQ4VLVTYRqEmlymbm94NXiVUOLCVWFjIlPZ/s6hts6V6pMtTAJKYoQXLJJqaYNiVm0ZcUT7KIWfKlsicBXfGlqh@HQpa@nqdLkjORGpNuF@bz8JD6nysRZ9wfZu@7Tua0uTzM5JoN50jXzrrrViNdUZ36YDA@WDu4ttM3w1i6iUsMPTuL49/h8OepRzF0GwdbqVR1kT7HwQ34SQv0Ixz8jd2UKG3i4BV@fxqhBzi47z0KYXoPB38Qz6MQvY1tlbiO52kNBwfL4eUc/QoHHwTiZkAf4uCvoRon/m3O7ryizuhbHLweKZ9Hn@DgSVj94tFlHHwR0W1OL@PghbXE541s1e6C5R7oF47lTMuZ2tba@3T9mbHxdrBzJNUbu3cvP3zeSxdeL2@f3kpOubYY7wRoA5d6a8FSZvtiCUerUcOA76p5HN2L6Mfenqzg6GxYrYkd/SmOPgtpq7PzADlyaWFb4zSy5rk5@SY4iw5w9NyWtz93kiE/7LW4RZeIlOPvG9JK6BSVcLSocqoVPoOR/X4S95UmUh0c/ZHfu9Hzv4ejR7OzL0x/xNH3cfsDmt6POyIT0an86arD0RFDF5Ad68b@ayqdX6/1N/da/c3sevbze1dXFOXU@OrcfSoedzLDgWRopebZdg79nwt7/QY)

That's a chonker of a Vim program right there. The inputted cube requires a padding of spaces around the sides. Additionally, I used `█` instead of `¶` as the stopping point, but that is only because `¶` has a special meaning in V. You can replace the `█` with `¶` and it will run just fine in Vim.